# gitla-ci: use a counter as a variable in scheduler

Tags: gitlab-ci

In my gitlab job scheduler I like to use a counter:
[image]

I can create a random one, but is there a way to get a simple counter so the next run will have 14 instead of 13.

Reason is that I then can easily see age on hostname of the testnodes.

Any way to use the api?

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined variable `CI_PIPELINE_IID` which increments by 1 for each pipeline in the project. That usually can be used for these kinds of purposes.

```
variables:
  ACMEHOSTNAME: acme-autodeploy-test-$CI_PIPELINE_IID
```

Otherwise, if you need more explicit control, you could also use the [project variables API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html).